# error when using class constructor parameter in "where" method

Tags: flutter, dart, class

I'm trying to pass a string as a parameter in the constructor to be used as a parameter of the where method, but when trying to use the parameter CampoPesquisaNome it returns an error.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class listFireBase extends StatefulWidget {
  final String campoPesquisaNome;
  listFireBase(this.campoPesquisaNome, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<listFireBase> createState() => _listFireBaseState();
}

class _listFireBaseState extends State<listFireBase> {
   final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('MeusContatos')
      .where('Nome', isEqualTo: widget.campoPesquisaNome) // ERROR HERE
      .snapshots();

...
```

Error:

```
lib/list-firebase.dart:15:33: Error: Undefined name 'widget'.
      .where('Nome', isEqualTo: widget.campoPesquisaNome)
                                ^^^^^^
```

Nothing I tried worked

Answer (score 0):

`widget` cannot be accessed in an initializer. You can add the `late` keyword, and either initialize the stream in the `initState` or right there.

```dart
late final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('MeusContatos')
      .where('Nome', isEqualTo: widget.campoPesquisaNome) // NO MORE ERROR HERE
      .snapshots();
```